mysql deadlock when running vitest tests and knex
I'm building integration tests for my repository layer, but I'm facing a deadlock issue because of the run of parallel tests, i used transactions to try to solve this problem but I'm still getting deadlocks here is an example of my tests:
import db from '../../../../db/db';
import EntityFactory from '../../../common/__tests__/entityFactory';
import { workspaceRepository } from '../workspaceRepository';

describe.skip('workspaceRepository', () => {
    let trx: any;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        trx = await db.transaction();
        await trx.schema.alterTable('workspaces', (table: any) => {
            table.dropForeign('ownerId');
        });
        await Promise.all([
            EntityFactory.createWorkspace(trx, 1, 1, 'workspace1', 'description', 'url'),
        ]);
    });

    test('createWorkspace', async () => {
        const workspace = await workspaceRepository.createWorkspace(trx, {
            ownerId: 3,
            name: 'workspace5',
            description: 'description',
            avatarUrl: 'url',
        });
        expect(workspace.id).not.toBeNull();
        const workspaces = await trx.select('*').from('workspaces');
        expect(workspaces).toHaveLength(2);
        await EntityFactory.deleteWorkspaces(trx, [workspace.id]);
    });

    test('getAllUserWorkspaces', async () => {
        const workspaces = await workspaceRepository.findAllUserWorkspaces(trx, 1);
        expect(workspaces).toHaveLength(1);
    });

        // more tests. 

    afterAll(async () => {
        await Promise.all([EntityFactory.deleteWorkspaces(trx, [1])]);
        await trx.schema.alterTable('workspaces', (table: any) => {
            table.foreign('ownerId').references('id').inTable('users');
        });
        trx.commit();
    });
}, 15000);

here is the content of my repository:
import { CreateWorkspaceDto, Workspace } from '@/api/workspace/workspaceModel';

export const workspaceRepository = {
    createWorkspace: async (trx: any, workspace: CreateWorkspaceDto): Promise<Workspace> => {
        const ids = await trx('workspaces').insert(workspace);
        const newWorkspace = await trx('workspaces').where('id', ids[0]).first();
        return newWorkspace;
    },
    findAllUserWorkspaces: async (trx: any, userId: number): Promise<Workspace[]> => {
        return await trx.select('*').from('workspaces').where('ownerId', userId);
    },

    findById: async (trx: any, id: number): Promise<Workspace | null> => {
        return await trx.select('*').from('workspaces').where('id', id).first();
    },
    deleteWorkspace: async (trx: any, id: number): Promise<void> => {
        await trx('workspaces').where('id', id).delete();
    },
};

error:
 FAIL  src/api/coworkers/__tests__/04_coworkersRepository.test.ts > coworkerRepository
Error: alter table `coworkers` drop foreign key `coworkers_userid_foreign` - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

 ❯ Packet.asError node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17
.
.
.

Serialized Error: { code: 'ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK', errno: 1213, sqlState: '40001', sqlMessage: 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction', sql: 'alter table `coworkers` drop foreign key `coworkers_userid_foreign`' }
--------------------------------------------------------

 FAIL  src/api/coworkers/__tests__/04_coworkersRepository.test.ts > coworkerRepository
Error: alter table `coworkers` add constraint `coworkers_userid_foreign` foreign key (`userId`) references `users` (`id`) - Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'coworkers_userid_foreign'
 ❯ Packet.asError node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17
.
.

Serialized Error: { code: 'ER_FK_DUP_NAME', errno: 1826, sqlState: 'HY000', sqlMessage: 'Duplicate foreign key constraint name \'coworkers_userid_foreign\'', sql: 'alter table `coworkers` add constraint `coworkers_userid_foreign` foreign key (`userId`) references `users` (`id`)' }

what am i missing here, is there is a way to it better?

Alter table is a DDL-type statement, which are not part of transactions and thus cannit cause deadlocks. I would check the innodb status monitor right after you get the deadlocks error to find out what causes the deadlock.
